# Is there a way to split CSS using the asset pipeline?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

The end result of what I'm trying to achieve is rather than having a single `applications.css` file, I want to split it into two sections -- a section I'm going to inline into the `<head>` tag, and then everything else. The reasoning behind this is that we want to inline the portion of our CSS that applies to above-the-fold elements of the page.

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to leverage the asset pipeline to remove the portion of the CSS that's inlined from the `application.css` file?

I feel like this is one of those problems where the way I'm thinking about the problem may be the biggest blocker, so totally open to alternative ways to think about this (i.e. not using the asset pipeline).

Just to make the problem more interesting, ideally I'd like a way to do this that's independent of the project itself, because there are multiple Rails front-ends where I'll need to apply this technique.

**NOTE:** Determining which part of the CSS I want to inline is not the problem -- that I have solved. What I'm looking for is a way to, as we continue to update our CSS in the future, make generating the two parts of the CSS a simple rake task, or integrated into the asset pipeline so it's done on deploy, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the most straightforward way of doing this, if we assume that the asset pipeline (a.k.a. [`sprockets`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md)) is the right approach, is extending `sprockets` via an exporter -- the thing that actually writes assets to disk.

**Update:** I've instead looked at [css-purge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-purge) as an off-the-shelf solution for identifying which CSS is used on a given page. Having this as a separate tool that doesn't care that a given page was generated via a Rails app helps make it more useful.